ubuntu 6.5.0.34 won't boot
as summarized here:
I am posting a screenshot since did not know how else could address
Anyway, someone mentioned that 22.04 is 6.8 kernel. How to update?
I used boot-recovery and still nothing

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS uses the 6.8 kernel, it won't be available for some time as the HWE kernel stack in 22.04; with Ubuntu 22.04 being 22.04.4 currently and the 6.5 kernel rolling out at 22.04.5 which if you look at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906 isn't until 29 August 2024; though the kernel will be available before that as -edge, but it's still some time away.  5.15 & 6.5 are currently the GA & HWE kernel stacks for 22.04 LTS.

FYI:  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04-edge | 6.5.0.34.34~22.04.1 | jammy-proposed  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x is the current edge- kernel available... ie. its still 6.5 with 6.8 still in the near-future.

-1: The title confusingly does not match the body of the question. Title claims "won't boot". The linked image offers no information at all about what won't boot or why. The description seems asking about how to use the wrong kernel for your release of Ubuntu. Not sure what you are really asking, but I'll guess at one of them and try to answer that.

"[s]omeone mentioned that 22.04 is 6.8 kernel."
You have been misled.

Ubuntu 24.04 currently uses the 6.8 kernel.
Ubuntu 22.04 (HWE kernel) uses the 6.5 kernel, and will upgrade to the 6.8 kernel when 22.04.5 is released around August 2024.
Ubuntu 22.04 (GA kernel) uses the 5.15 kernel, and will continue to do so.


ok, still the same problem. It is already  August 2024. When upgrading, says: installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10

That does not seem like the same problem. It does not resemble anything you described in your question above. Perhaps you might open a new question for this new problem.
